# double pointers w/o array notation

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I'm trying to iterate through a double pointer without using Array notation. I've been given these guidelines through my instructor.

In .h file:

```
int** A, B, C;
```

In .c file

```
void initNumbers() {

    int** a = A;
    int** b = B;
    int** c = C;

    int* p;// = *a;
    int* q;// = *b;
    int* r;// = *c; 

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        p = *a;
        q = *b;
        r = *c;
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            *r = rand() % 50;
            *p = rand() % 50;
            *q = rand() % 50;
            p++;
            q++;
            r++;
        }
        a++;
        b++;
        c++;
    }
}
```

I've allocated memory via.

```
void initNumSpace() {
    A = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 10);
    B = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 10);
    C = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 10);

    int** a = A;
    int** b = B;
    int** c = C;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
        b = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
        c = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);

        a++;
        b++;
        c++;
    }
}
```

The code gets no syntax errors, but there is a segmentation fault at the very first iteration of the imbedded loop of initNumbers. Why is this happening? What is the best way to iterate through a pointer array without array notation e.g., indices or offset values.

Comment: In addition int** A, B, C are global variables accessable via header files.

Comment: `a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);` should be `*a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);`. And the same for `b` and `c`.

Comment: You may be able to find insight using debugging tools such as an interactive debugger and/or a sanitizer like ASan. I've prepared an example with your code under ASan [here](https://godbolt.org/z/j5nK7GhcP) (notice that I passed a few more compiler flags `-fsanitize=address -Og -g` to enable the sanitizer and get better debug info) - in this case Barmar's comment points out the actual issue, and seeing this would be easier in an interactive debugger, but I still recommend that you check it out as a good tool for the future.

Comment: I cannot post another question because of my current status, but I'm struggling to deallocate the memory which was allocated within this code. The same guidlines apply. Does anyone have advice? I will post a second q in 90 mins if this question isn't enough to give an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a few problems.

First of all, you shouldn't **DEFINE** variables in header files; you should only **DECLARE** them. That is, you if you wanted to declare an integer N, then you shouldn't write `int N;` but instead `extern int N;` and then go to your source file and write `int N;` to define it. C (and C++) have the multiple declaration-one definition rule: you can declare something as many times as you like (you can write 'extern int A;`five times in a row and the compiler won't mind), but you have to define each variable and function exactly once (you should write`int A;` exactly once in a source file.

Secondly, there's a slight problem with your header file. In C, writing `int** A,B,C;` is the same as `int **A;int B;int C;`. `A` is a double pointer, but `B` and `C` are integers. So, you should write `int **A,**B,**C;` (or even better, write each one on a separate line).

Your code should now look like this:

HEADER:

```
int** A;
int** B;
int** C;
```

SOURCE:

```
void initNumSpace() {
    A = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 10);
    B = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 10);
    C = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 10);
    
    int** a = A;
    int** b = B;
    int** c = C;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        //you should dereference these btw
        *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
        *b = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10); 
        *c = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10); 

        a++;
        b++;
        c++;
    }
}

void initNumbers() {

    int** a = A;
    int** b = B;
    int** c = C;

    int* p;// = *a;
    int* q;// = *b;
    int* r;// = *c; 

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        p = *a;
        q = *b;
        r = *c;
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            *r = rand() % 50;
            *p = rand() % 50;
            *q = rand() % 50;
            p++;
            q++;
            r++;
        }
        a++;
        b++;
        c++;
    }
}
```

PS: why are you doing this way? It's not wrong, but it's really comlicated and hard to read. Why would you not want to use array indexing (`[]`).

Answer (score -1):

The error is in your init function. The double pointers get set to the newly allocated space, but the pointer array A does not get set to the value of a.
Try this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    *b = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    *c = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);

    a++;
    b++;
    c++;
}
```

Update: You also have to change the type of B and C to int*, or int**. Otherwise this may not work on systems, which are not 32bit. (void* would have to be of size int and the indexing also has to be the same for this to work).
Using int in this context at all is kind of a liability, since the size of int is defined differently on different systems and it is not consistent with the size of void*. You can use int32_t and such from stdint.h for better compatability.

Comment: I was unlcear about my global variables. They are defined outside of the main function. Otherwise this was a solution to my problem. Thank you

Comment: True, but there are also other problems.

Comment: The question was about the segmentation fault, so thats what you should focus on. In C a double pointer is just a value anyways and if you dont intend to use the bracket syntax, it doesnt matter. You didnt even mention the actual problem XD

Comment: Yes, but if you had actually bothered to read the entire question, you would have noticed that he declared only `A` to be a double pointer, and B and C are ints, and that he incorrectly placed the definitions inside the header file which I think are also pretty signifacant, since they too will produce compilation errors.

Comment: *segmentation faults

Comment: `int **A, B, C; // only A is pointer, others are int` but `int** A,B,C;` are different

Comment: Update: This actually does not work on 64bit systems, since sizeof(void*) is 8, but sizeof(int) can be 4. This means you would loose the 4 MSB in B = malloc(...), resulting in an possibly invalid pointer.
I only work with 32bit µcs, so this was never an issue for me.

Comment: @SDao and Menroka that is what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: In header file there is `int** A, B, C;` means they are both pointers. All mallocs are correct, work on both 32/64 bits system. The only thing waste here is 10 elements for storing the pointers which We can archive the same by just use simple array of int with size of (cols x rows) instead. Use pointers to iterate over it. The down side is if the size of array are large, and we do have to malloc/free frequently, it might out-of-memory sometime (since use single array requires large continuously memory portion) due to memory fragmentation.

Comment: @SDao int** A,B,C does not declare three pointers, see [C Pointer tutorial](https://edoras.sdsu.edu/doc/c/pointers-1.2.2/).
Yes, you could do with just one big Array, but I dont think, that was the point of the excersise.

Comment: Try it yourself.